# iTunes refuses Apple ID password 3 times before loading

Tags: passwords, itunes, apple-id

Every time I launch Itunes on my WIndows10 machine I am unable to successfully log into the Itunes Store despite that the entered password is correct Itunes. I have to enter the password correctly 3 times before it allows me to continue:

[image]

I find this a waste of time, especially considering I have no use for the Itunes store in the first place. Being asked for my password for Itunes store when I open the app is a horrible feature I would like to disable if possible.

So I'd like to remedy this by either:
1 - disabling the iTunes store
2 - finding out why I need to enter my password 3 times (I would prefer if it just remembered by PW if this is the only option).

I am running iTunes Version 12.11.0.26 on Windows 10 Pro 20HN

Comment: Have you tried unistalling and reinstalling the application?

Answer (score 0):

If you have any special characters in your password, try writing the password in a text editor like notepad, copy it from there and paste it into itunes.